# Using DrawingContext to create XpsDocuments in different sizes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I need to create different reports which will be printed on different page sizes (A4, A5, etc).

In the past we used Winforms (e.graphics.DrawString etc) to build up the page.
We now migrated to WPF and are using XpsDocument. I'm new to WPF and I'm a bit lost in the different printing and drawing classes.

How can I create an A4 page for example, and draw a string at x=100mm, y=150mm?
If it's possible I would like to use the DrawingContext class, because it seems to resemble the winforms GDI+ style of drawing the page contents

```
DrawingVisual visual = new DrawingVisual();
using (DrawingContext dc = visual.RenderOpen())
{
      dc.DrawText(new FormattedText("TestString 01", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
            , FlowDirection.LeftToRight, new Typeface("Arial"), 10, Brushes.Black)
            , new Point(100, 150));
}
```

I'm using the following code to create the XPS document, but I don't know how to set page size, and use DrawingContext on the XPS document ...

```
using (var doc = new XpsDocument(fileName, FileAccess.Write))
{
    var writer = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(doc);
    writer.Write(GetRandomA4Page());
}
```

Comment: You wouldn't usually use a DrawingVisual in order to print a document. Start reading the [Documents in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748388.aspx) article on MSDN.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I'm now using a FixedDocument with TextBlock instances, and that seems to be all I need. Thanks again.